# VueJs reactivity with parent component property object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having difficulty to get parent component's property object, with dynamically populated properties to make the values available inside of the same component.

A bit hard to explain, so please have a look at the example below:

**Parent Component**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                fields: {},
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
  <select
      @change="update()"
      v-model="field"
  >
      <option
          v-for="option in options"
          :value="option.value"
      >
          {{ option.name }}
      </option>
  </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            initialOptions: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                    field: '',
                options: this.initialOptions
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            if (
                (this.field === undefined || this.field === '') &&
                this.options.length > 0
            ) {
                this.field = this.options[0].value;
            }
            this.update();
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                this.$emit('input', this.field);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**DOM**

```
<parent-component inline-template>

    <div>

        <child-component>           
            :initial-options="[{..}, {..}]"
          v-model="fields.type_id"
        ></child-component>

    </div>

    <div :class="{ dn : fields.type_id == 2 }">

        // ...

    </div>

</parent-component>
```

Using Vue console I can see that `fields` object gets all of the child component models with their associated values as they emit `input` when they are mounted, however for some strange reason the `:class="{ dn : fields.type_id == 2 }"` does not append the class `dn` when the selection changes to `2`. Dom doesn't seem to reflect the changes that are synced between parent and child components.

Any help on how to make it work?

Comment: How are you adding properties to the parent `fields`?

Comment: Using `v-model` directive on the child component and on `mounted` emitting `input` event with associated value from each child component.

Comment: Can you show it? What I'm getting at is `fields` is starting off as an empty object. If you are adding properties to that incorrectly, then Vue will not be able to detect the changes.

Comment: It is in the example above - please check `Child Component` section and then `DOM` where child component gets `v-model`. You'll see that on `mounted` there is a call to `update()` method, which emits the event.

Comment: When/how does `fields: {}` get a property called `type_id`?

Comment: It's added dynamically via `v-model`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I was trying to get at in comments. Vue [cannot detect changes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) to properties that are added dynamically to an object unless you add them using [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). Your `fields` object does not have a `type_id` property, but it gets added because you are using `v-model="fields.type_id"`. As such, Vue does not know when it changes.

Here, I have added it and the color of the text changes as you would expect.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("child-component", {
  template: `
    <select
        @change="update()"
        v-model="field"
    >
        <option
            v-for="option in options"
            :value="option.value"
        >
            {{ option.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
  `,
  props: {
    initialOptions: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      field: '',
      options: this.initialOptions
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (
      (this.field === undefined || this.field === '') &&
      this.options.length > 0
    ) {
      this.field = this.options[0].value;
    }
    this.update();
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.$emit('input', this.field);
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fields: {
      type_id: null
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dn {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <child-component :initial-options="[{name: 'test', value: 1}, {name: 'test2', value: 2}]" v-model="fields.type_id"></child-component>
  </div>
  <div :class="{ dn : fields.type_id == 2 }">
    Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a shame as this way I will always have to pass them through to the parent controller via props - all that for absolutely no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a re-usable  component.

I would ask myself what the value of a re-usable  component is when the parent component has to handle more than half of the effort.  The component might be better named...

```
 <DifficultToUseSelect/>.
```

Essentially, you are creating a component that provides, all by itself, all of the following HTML...

```
<select></select>
```

Everything else is managed by the parent component.

It would probably be more useful to do any of the following...

- Encapsulate often needed options in a specific select component, as in

  StateAbbrevsSelect v-model="state"
- Pass the name of a data model to a select component.  The component would then load and manage its own data via the model.
- Pass the URL of a web service to the component, which it then calls to load its options.

Again, the main point I am trying to convey here is that making a re-usable component where more than half of the effort is handled by the parent component is really not very re-usable.